# Terraform ignore nested block inside a resource with terraform conditional value

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I need to ignore blob properties if the account kind is file storage, I have tried using for each with dynamic but it keeps giving error.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {

  name                      = var.name
  location                  = var.location
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  account_kind              = var.account_kind
  account_tier              = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type  = var.replication_type
  min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
  enable_https_traffic_only = true


  blob_properties {
    dynamic "ignore_filestorage" {
      for_each = var.account_kind == FileStorage ? 0 : 1
      delete_retention_policy {
        days = var.blob_retention_days
      }
      container_delete_retention_policy {
        days = var.container_retention_days
      }
    }
  }
```

> error - Blocks of type "ignore_filestorage" are not expected here.
> error-  A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

If "account_kind" is specified as "filestorage" in var.tf then blob peroperties needs to ignored.

I tried using for each with dynamic but Keeps getting error and can't use count either inside a nested block.

Comment: `azure_storage_account` does not have an ignore_filestorage block. you probably want `dynamic "blob_properties" {`

Comment: Can I just do , "blob_properties" { 
count = var.account_kind 0:1 ?

Comment: No, you can do the same as you tried with `ignore_filestorage`.

Comment: what would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and the resource documentation, you probably want something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {

  name                      = var.name
  location                  = var.location
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  account_kind              = var.account_kind
  account_tier              = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type  = var.replication_type
  min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
  enable_https_traffic_only = true


  dynamic "blob_properties" {
    for_each = var.account_kind == "FileStorage" ? [] : [1]
    content {
      delete_retention_policy {
         days = var.blob_retention_days
      }
      container_delete_retention_policy {
        days = var.container_retention_days
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for_each` takes a set, not a number. You can't pass it the values 0 or 1. You need to pass it either an empty list, or a list of the size you want to create.

Please take the time to look at [the documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) and understand the differences between `count` and `for_each`.

For exmaple:

```
for_each = var.account_kind == FileStorage ? [] : [1]
```

That would create 0 dynamic blocks if `var.account_kind == FileStorage`, and one dynamic block if `var.account_kind != FileStorage`.

Note that the value in `[1]` is just a placeholder to make the list of size `1`. The value could be anything, like `["stackoverflow"]`.